# Value Error No JSON object could be decoded setting default for missing values

Tags: python, json, key-value

I am using VBA to get some user input data out from Excel to python, the data entries that cause me problems look like this, they are in file.json

```
[{"ExclusionList_var": [
[
    "Exclusion List",
    "Name",
    "Rank",
    "Rec",
    "Min",
    "Max",
    "Relative",
    "Active",
    "Date",
    "Dupe?",
    "Comment"
  ],
  [
    "6076146",
    ,
    ,
    ,
    -0.002,
    0.002,
    "Y",
    ,
    null,
    "",
    "Mega Structure"
  ]]}]
```

It looks like as the missing values are causing the problem, in python I just do this.

```
with open("file.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

Is there are default case to detect those values and set them to " " or null? I cannot do this at the json creation side as this is direct user input.

Comment: This isn't valid JSON. How did you generate the file in the first place? The best fix would be there.

Comment: This was me stripping down the json for an example i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: There is not really an easy way to "fix" the JSON before loading it, is there a way to create it properly on the creation side of the block?

=======

There were a few things wrong with the JSON block which is causing errors doing a string to JSON conversion

A few things: the lines that are just commas (`,`) are not proper JSON, if you need empty spaces, I would suggest using an empty string (`""`)

The second part is that the brackets and braces at the bottom are not in the same order that you have at the top. Here is a working JSON object:

```
[
  {
    "ExclusionList_var": [
      [
        "Exclusion List",
        "Name",
        "Rank",
        "Rec",
        "Min",
        "Max",
        "Relative",
        "Active",
        "Date",
        "Dupe?",
        "Comment"
      ],
      [
        "6076146",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        -0.002,
        0.002,
        "Y",
        "",
        null,
        "",
        "Mega Structure"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Is there a way of letting the json parser fill in the empty strings ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, my best advice would be to see if the creation side of this can put either an empty string or `null` in the place of it